# D3js Stacked-to-Grouped (convert to time)

Tags: d3.js

I am attempting to understand some of how D3 (or really more Javascript itself) is using things like map, stack, and transpose) to do what it is doing in the Stacked-to-Grouped example so that I can change the data to use my data of Dates and totals and names so that I can group by a date in my data and then put that data on a timescale so that it is still grouped but by date and the colors change by name.

My data looks like this..

```
data = [{"id":"1", "month":"4", "total":"1", "year":"2012", "ename":"Jamie"},
{"id":"1", "month":"3", "total":"5", "year":"2013", "ename":"Jamie"},
{"id":"2", "month":"1", "total":"6", "year":"2012", "ename":"Joe"},
{"id":"2", "month":"3", "total":"7", "year":"2013", "ename":"Joe"},
{"id":"3", "month":"2", "total":"1", "year":"2012", "ename":"Jeri"},
{"id":"3", "month":"4", "total":"5", "year":"2012", "ename":"Jeri"},
{"id":"4", "month":"3", "total":"3", "year":"2013", "ename":"Ron"},
{"id":"4", "month":"7", "total":"8", "year":"2013", "ename":"Ron"},
{"id":"5", "month":"3", "total":"5", "year":"2013", "ename":"Ann"},
{"id":"5", "month":"4", "total":"1", "year":"2012", "ename":"Ann"}]
```

You can see where I set it up at the end of the script, what I need to know is what I need to do to convert it so that the chart works and is on a timescale instead.

Here is my fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/jamiebrs/pdsxz59m/

Comment: Let's forget about code for a while and talk about data visualisation: you shouldn't use a time scale here. A time scale represents precisely this, **time**! If you use a time scale, it will be an absolute hell to keep an even distance for the ticks, because a time scale takes into account Feb with only 28 days, leap years, even daylight saving changes! (but that's not noticeable here, since you're using years for the ticks). On top of that, the left side of the bars will be positioned on the given date, giving you extra headache to centering them (continue...)

Comment: So, all that being said, your "year" here don't represent time, but a categorical variable instead! Keep the band scale.

Comment: I suspected as much as far as the time goes. That said how would I change this current graph to use my data below?

Comment: So I changed this up to use a different example with my data. I am using this block - https://bl.ocks.org/alandunning/ab4b0b203f58ce4c42754774c85c0119

What I would like to figure out if there is a way to at least maybe fake my xAxis to look like a timeline where the 0 is my starting date and the end of the axis my ending date?

Here is my fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/jamiebrs/qp0j3h1z/